# Survey on Erdős-Pósa?

Tags: reference-request, directed-acyclic-graph, survey, graph-minor

Does anyone know of any good surveys on Erdős-Pósa?

I am particularly interested in what are the latest results for the bounding function for directed and even cycles in planar and minor free graphs down to the constant factor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know about a survey, but I've found a recent PhD thesis, which seems to be well written:

Heinlein, Matthias (2019): Erdős-Pósa properties. Open Access Repositorium der Universität Ulm. Dissertation. http://dx.doi.org/10.18725/OPARU-11828

The first chapter gives a summary of the problem, known proof techniques and provides references to recent research. I am not an expert on this problem and only skimmed the first chapter briefly, so YMMV.